# UI freeze when creating a new window on a button click

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am new with Titanium, and I am facing a problem.
In my app.js, I am including a left menu and controls to the window (app.js and leftmenu.js)

I want to load a window when user clicks on menu item. Very basically, I want to load the app.js main window when user selects the homepage button.
For this, I've the following code into the leftmenu.js file :

```
var newWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    url: "app.js",
    zIndex: 0
});
win.close(); // closing main window
leftMenu.close(); // closing left menu
newWin.open(); //should reload the main window and the leftmenu
```

It reloads the window, but all controls are disable. We cannot click on any control. It is just like if all controls were under an invisible layer.
Any idea ?

I copy / paste the code portion, maybe it will be more clear :)

```
btnaccueil.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
   var newWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({        
       url: &quot;app.js&quot;,
       zIndex: 0
   });

   // Closing current instance for freeing memory
   win.close();
   leftMenu.close();
   newWin.open({animated:true});
   Ti.API.info(var_dump(newWin));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i know its a month later, but are you using require's and exports/module.exports? here is an example on how to open a new window with a button event the proper way, i think using url property is deprecated, so i hope this example can help you to understand

**employee.js**

```
//Current window (employee window)
var employeeWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

//define button
var moveToDetailBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
   width      : 200,      //define the width of button
   height      : 50,      //define height of the button
   title         : 'Show Detail'   //Define the text on button
});

//Click event to open the Employee Details window
moveToDetailBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){

   //Call a export function
   var win = require('employeeDetails').getEmployeeDetailSWin;

   //Create new instance
   var employeeDetailsWin = new win();

   //Open the Employee Details window
   employeeDetailsWin.open();
});

//Add the button to the window
employeeWin.add(moveToDetailBtn);
```

**In employeeDetails.js**

```
exports.getEmployeeDetailSWin = function(){

   //Creates a new window
   var empDetailsWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
      backgroundColor   : '#ffffff'      //Define the backgroundcolor of the window
   });

   //Addin a label to the window
   empDetailsWin.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
      width      : 100,      //Define width of the label
      height      : 50,      //Define height of the label
      title         : 'Employee Details'
   }));

   return empDetailsWin;
};
```

*besides i'm not sure if you can export your app.js try to use a new .js*